# I cannot debug in Android Studio. My service never attaches to VM and never stops on breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio

Typical output in Debugger view:

> Waiting for device. Target device: unknown_1-stv100_4-1161305457
>   Uploading file local path:
>   /Users/homedir/devel6/avengers/packages/inputmethods/BlackBerryLatinIME/build/outputs/apk/My_APK_FILE-debug.apk
>   remote path: /data/local/tmp/MY_SERVICE No apk changes detected.
>   Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead. DEVICE SHELL
>   COMMAND: am force-stop MY_SERVICE Waiting for process: MY_SERVICE

Then in 90% of case it starts to spam view screen with message:

> Client not ready yet.

Comment: uninstall your application and try again.

Comment: I did it many times. No result.

Comment: It's happened between 1.2 and 1.4. After that I switched between tcpip and USB, manually uninstalled/installed package, re-installed AS and SDK - no chance. The project is valid (other people use it). What is  may be suspicious are two versions of Java installed: 7 (JAVA_HOME) and 8 JDK_STUDIO)

Comment: At the same time, sample projects work well.What is the difference? Size? Barely...

Comment: May be this is useful information: logcat output contains a lot of messages like that:

Comment: does it work on simulator?

Comment: did you find a solution? got same problem since few weeks and same message, client not ready yet ..

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. 
After I just add below codes to onCreate(), the problem is resolved.

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

After I use android studio, I removed above code. Because studio works well without above codes unlike eclipse. 
But after update studio, I could not debug. It says like below

```
Waiting for process:
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
Client not ready yet.
```

It's not connected to the target VM.

Comment: This resolved the issue in my case with a very slow ARM emulator without hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

For android studio select **Run**--->**Attach debugger to android process** that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's sad to say, but I lost a lot of time in my battle with wind mills. The problem was in bad naming of packages. As soon as it was fixes, problem disappeared. I understand that it is my responsibility to fix such error. But it seems to me that Android Studio could provide a bit more diagnostics.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am facing the same issue. What was the problem with package name ?

Comment: I had this problem after changing my app's namespace.  I fixed it by deleting the app/target directory.

Comment: My problem was that I rename my project folder with a name with "spaces" and Android Studio didn't like that

Answer (score 0):

phone setting should set on **MTP mode** and nothing else. debugger connects to my phone after this change.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs on some phones when debugging, probably because of some error logs are not printed out, but when I move to another phone can see the error。
like:
I do not have permission to add the following error message in less than one plus phone watch Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online 
android.permission.INTERNET

but When I can see some errors when use nexus5.

Answer (score 0):

This thing happen to me too, the problem was that i disable instant run, just enabling instant-run, fix the problem, check it
Go to:
File -> Settings ->Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run
And Enable Instant Run
Should do the trick